# How do you find suitable substitutions for double integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have solved several 'trivial' substitution problems like polar coordinates and $x = 2u$, $y = 3v$. However I do not intuitively see the following substitutions :

$x = \frac{u}{v}$ and $y = v$ for $\iint_{D} xy \:dA$, where $D$ denotes the region surrounded by $y = x$, $y = 3x$, $xy = 1$, and $xy = 3$.

$x = u^{2} - v^{2}$ and $y = 2uv$ for $\iint_{D} y \:dA$, where $D$ denotes the region surrounded by $y^{2} = 4 - 4x$ and $y^{2} = 4 + 4x$.

I understand that it works for some reason, but I can't think of those when the substitution is not given. Are there any tips? Or is it just memorizing those 'potentially possible substitutions'? (Both examples include each substitution, and the problem was like 'Evaluate the following double integral by using the substitution $x = \frac{u}{v}$ and $y = v$', but there are other problems where they don't give any hints about substitution.)

Answer (score 1):

I usually try to find new variables which make the equations for the boundaries of the region constant.  In your first example, I'd see the equations $xy=1$ and $xy=3$ and that would make we want to have one substitution $v=xy$.  If you divide the other two equations by $x$ you have $y/x=1$ and $y/x=3$, so that would make me want to use $u = y/x$.  Now my region in the $uv$-plane is a rectangle.  If you solve the two substitutions for $x$ and $y$, you'll get the suggested substitution.

For your second example, I don't see right off, but the two boundary curves are $y^2+4x=$ constant and $y^2-4x=$ constant, so I'd start with $u=y^2+4x$ and $v=y^2-4x$ and start playing around.  (Is the problem copied right?)